# Execute code on Angular 8 Page when be visible to the user

Tags: angular, angular8

There is a way on Angular's lifecycle to execute some code every time page becomes visible to the user? I've searched about ngOnChanges(), but I think it not works to this.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is not clear still I figured something.
I think you want to display a particular view after full page load.
So suppose if you have a `GET`  request which loads all data from server, you have to load the view after the load completes. By default initialise a variable `isLoading=true`. Then in `ngOnInit()` do this:

```
function().subscribe(response => this.isLoading = false)
```

In view HTML the particular view you want to display after full load set it to `*ngIf=!isLoading`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Use `ngOnInit()`  method for executing some code every time page. This method will be automatically add while creating a angular component.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

   //
  }
```

You can set the visibility by using `*ngIf` directive along with a boolean variable.

In html file  :

```
<span *ngIf="is_visible" > content to be display based on the condtion </span>
```

In your component.ts file :

```
 public is_visiblae : boolean = false;
 ngOnInit(): void {
       is_visible=true;
      }
```